# How to find optimized x values (input features) after training in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, optimization

I did deep learning training by Keras.

I have done the training part by model.fit If I do model.predict, it only gives me y value. But I want to know x (input features) that gives the best y value, which means the optimized x values after training.

Is there any way to fetch the optimized x values (input features) in Keras or else?

I really appreciate your help.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by optimized X values? You cannot change your input features, they are as is, based on which your model predicts i.e produces Y.

Comment: @NischalHp hello. I thought after we could find some optimized input features as we lower loss function at each epoch. Then if I wanna find optimized input features, what kind of machine learning technique should I use? Thank you.

Comment: I Still do not understand your question, why do you want to find optimized input features? 

What is the problem you are trying to solve? What is the input to your network? What is the network doing?

Comment: Hello, prople from the past! I think I'm in the same boat as @junmouse. In my case, I'm having a hard time figuring out the best hyper parameters to use on my model so I've started to randomly test hyper parameter combinations and record the results (accuracy, loss, etc.). Now I want to use the results in a separate model to find hyper parameter combinations that yield the best accuracy, lowest losses, etc. for my first model. I imagine that it'll need to try a couple of times, but quickly the meta model should test strategies and gain data relevant to finding the optimal hyper parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to find the best features to optimize your model's performance?

I think what you're looking for is feature selection, which is an entire subject within machine learning/statistics. There is a whole tag on here about feature selection, you'd be better off asking your question with that. I would poke around a little online to learn more about feature selection, and if after that you still want help here you should provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve, the data you're working with, and more details about your model.

Comment: Hello. What I am looking for is not feature selection. I rather look for the best combination of specific feature values for example, when x values like temperature = 30, weight = 50, pressure = 100, the y value was the best. I wish you understood my question?

Comment: So you are referring to specific feature values and not features? This is not a good strategy as your model will overfit your training data and not generalize well to data the model hasn't seen.

Comment: I think it would help if you would give a more specific example. It sound like you want to find an optimum for the unknown y and then reverse the learned mapping to find out which feature values that maximum has. If that's your meaning, depending on the problem you are tryign to solve, you might belooking for something like polynomial regression. Here is for example a discussion about such a kind of thing https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23828/finding-local-minima-maxima-in-noisy-data

Answer (score 0):

The model doesn't know which X values would yield the "best" result.

You could run the model a couple of times (tf.predict()) with dummy data, record the results (inputs and predictions), build a Genetic ML model that optimizes X combinations for high (if that's what you consider "good") Y values.

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing special about your neural network. It is a function of some inputs. You know from (multivariable) calculus how to find the points giving maxima and minima of functions. The fact that your function is a deep neural network is basically irrelevant.

Note that there is no guarantee that a maximum exists. It might be that, the bigger you make some feature, the better the predicted outcome.

If you just want to know which observed combination of features gives the best predicted outcome, then run your observations through the predictive model and note which one gives the best prediction (much faster than training the network).